# IP camera Live video stream to iOS device

Tags: ios, ip-camera, live-video

I am trying to create an app that receives a live video stream from an ip camera. Originally I was considering using an outside server like Ivideon and then just embedding the video as an html webview within the app. I was just wondering how complicated it would be to get the feed directly from the ip cameras default server. I am very new to developing for iOS so I am hoping for as simple of a solution as possible.

Comment: did you find some solution?

Comment: anyone found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use VLC to re stream RTSP/RTP from IP camera to HLS and play it due to native support. If you want to get video directly from your app, the easiest way will be asking camera for JPEG images over HTTP.